# Positioning with CSS percentage margin

Tags: css

I have the strangest problem. The problem is with my `6.66% margin-bottom` for my nav bar. When I make the screen bigger horizontally, this (vertical) margin increases, I am completely stumped, why would this happen?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
}
main {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
}
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url('Index-Background.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: -1;
}
section {
  margin-left: 2%;
  width: 26%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 26.66%;
  border: 1px solid black
}
section > div {
  margin-top: 10%;
}
nav {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 6.66%;
  bottom-left: 10%;
}
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
nav ul li {
  padding: 0px 20px;
}
nav ul li a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h1>The Great Composers</h1>
      <div>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. rum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. The
        first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</div>
    </section>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#0">Bach</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Mozart</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Beethoven</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Chopin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Schubert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Tchaikovsky</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Gershwin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Debussy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: you'll need to supply the css for us to help you

Comment: posting your code would help,

Comment: I know, apparently you can't post from codepen

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your expectations are with using percent as a margin. It is working as expected taking the percent of its parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percentage is calculated as a percent of the containing block's width as you have discovered.

https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/box.html#margin-properties

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of
>   the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for
>   'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well.

Comment: Wow, ok. So would you recommend that I just use Rem/em? Percentage was very convenient because it allowed me a very proportional control of the webpage, is there no other good way to get that?

Comment: @Oli Assuming you want a fixed margin size and can allow for any changes in the font size which would affect changes in em. For proportional changes, I would search SO for solutions or ask another question.